# Autologin or autoclick on button

Tags: javascript, html, auto, autologin

I have HTML code which displays a pre-compiled login form. Is it possible to improve this code in order to make the login automatic, so it autofills the user information (name, password)?

```html
<html><body>

<form
id="myForm"
action="http://***.***.***.***/***/****/*******="
method="post">

Account name:<br>
<input name="****" value="****" />
<br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="pwd" value="****" />
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>

</body></html>
```

Comment: Describe "automatic".

Comment: @LazarLjubenović I think he meant clicking on the login button.

Comment: Why show a form if you're just going to log a user in automatically?

Comment: Yes i meant clicking on the login button... Zero298, you're right it's a strange request, but i need this feature in order to improve the login with a server, an app and with a website at the same time...

Answer (score 0):

Of course, just click on the button on load:

```
<html><body onload="document.getElementById('login').click();">

<form 
id="myForm" 
action="http://***.***.***.***/***/****/*******=" 
method="post">

Account name:<br>
<input name="****" value="****" />
<br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="pwd" value="****" />
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" id="login">
</form>

</body></html>
```

Comment: I tried to add this html code but it doesn't work, maybe i have to rename the id "load"? Thanks very much!

Comment: @alexs you are right, I have been inconsistent in the naming of the id. I have fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use JavaScript:

```js
function login() {
    document.getElementById("username").value = "username";
    document.getElementById("password").value = "password";
}
```

```html
<html><body>

<form id="myForm" action="http://***.***.***.***/***/****/*******=" method="post">

Account name:<br>
<input name="****" value="****" id="username" />
<br>
Password:<br>
<input type="password" name="pwd" value="****" id="password"/>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="login()" />
</form>

</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the jQuery submit event for your form. In your javascript use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to insert this code in wp in the visual composer object "JAVASCRIPT" but id doesn't work... maybe i'm doing something wrong?